# How to send named byte array parameters in android?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking, androidhttpclient

My app has hit a roadblock because I need to pass two arguments as folowing through http post request in android:

```
1st argument: Name: parameter1 Value:  String 
1st argument: Name: parameter2 Value: byte array
```

How to do it? I have searched a lot but not able to find any method.

Comment: have you tired by creating Json object.

Comment: but the requirement is byte data one argument is needed in string and other in byte

Comment: Use the `OutputStream` for body parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things in this problem -

1) Use HttpUrlConnection and set the requestProperty like below

```
 connection.setRequestProperty("ContentLength",Integer.toString(parameters.toString().getBytes().length));
```

2) Use MultipartFormData like below

```
 MultipartEntity form = new MultipartEntity();
 ContentBody cd = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(b), "myfile.txt");
 form.addPart("file", cd);
```

For MultipartFormData you can use Retrofit.